# Error: Resultset does not have a column 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Using the JDBC services to connect to a Google Cloud SQL and
 following the [example of the overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc) everything works as expected. 
When I try to do some other SQL statement like `select database();` 
I get the error : ***Resultset does not have a column 1***

This is the code I am using.

```
var sqlStatement = "select database();";
var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
var rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement);  
app.add(app.createLabel(rs.getString(1)));
```

I also tried with `getObject()` but it does get any better .

So any Idea, tutorials or examples how to deal with sqlStatements 
different than the tipical select like `use database` or
 `select database()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the statement to start the iterator - this is the .next() call on the record set. Here is an function that works for me. I am just logging the DB name here using Logger, but same should work for UiApp as well.

```
function simpleRead() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://arunnagarajan:...");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select database()");
  rs.next(); //if you expect multiple rows, then do this in while(rs.next()) loop
  Logger.log(rs.getString(1));
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Wokred like a charm tnahks, and how do I check the resutl of executing `use database`?

Comment: Great. `use database` doesn't return any results I believe. So reading from the resultset does not apply.

Comment: Maybe I should ask how do I confirm the execution of `use database` statement? Is there some ohter kind of return to check if there was an error or not executing a stametent that does not return a typical result set. thnaks!

Comment: You could run `use <database>` and then check the result of `select database()` to see if the `use` command was successful. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//information-functions.html#function_database

Comment: Yeah I know, but that is not a good deal if you are paying for Google Cloud SQL, traffic is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line, try

`app.add(app.createLabel(rs.getString(0)));`

Comment: sorry; it was my best guess.  :-)

Comment: I tried that but it gives the same error with a 0 at the end. By the way when you execute a SQL like `use database` the error is that a resultset cannot have a null value.